# Wordpress WP_Query "NOT IN" not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom field `Field Name: "participants"` with `Field Type: "User"`.

I want to use "NOT IN" in meta query but it is not working.

```
$getUid = $_REQUEST['uid'];
$args = [
    'post_type' => 'polls',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_query' => [
        'relation' => 'AND',
        [
            'key' => 'participants',
            'value' => [$getUid],
            'compare' => "NOT IN"
        ]
    ]
];

$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
return $the_query;
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "not working?" Error output or expected vs. actual outcome are helpful or even essential.

Answer (score 0):

USe this code and make sure you get value in $REQUEST['uid']

```
   $getUid = $_REQUEST['uid'];
    $meta_query_args = array(
        'relation' => 'AND', // Optional, defaults to "AND"
        array(
            'post_type' => 'polls',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
            'key' => 'participants',
                'value' => [$getUid],
                'compare' => "NOT IN"
        )
    );
    $meta_query = new WP_Meta_Query( $meta_query_args );
```

Comment: I am getting below output

Comment: WP_Meta_Query Object
(
    [queries] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [post_type] => polls
                    [post_status] => publish
                    [key] => participants
                    [value] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 1
                        )

                    [compare] => NOT IN
                )

            [relation] => OR
        )

    [relation] => AND
    [meta_table] => 
    [meta_id_column] => 
    [primary_table] => 
  ..

Comment: pass this output in $the_query = new WP_Query($meta_query);